# Cannot connect to Server via RDP after reboot

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

My company is in charge of many computers, one of which was recently rebooted due to swapping out a hard-disk cage.

Ever since then it just won't let me connect via RDP.
I have checked and restarted the corresponding services and used tools to find out that port 3389 is indeed open.

After re-enabling telnet, I'm also able to access the server via telnet.
However within seconds of trying to RDP it asks for credentials before denying the connection with a 2308 error.

After googling said number I've come to the conclusion that neither results helped me. The server only has a single NIC, so that should not be the problem.
and rebooting the server remotely again did also fix nothing.

We're talking Win 2008 SP2 here (not R2), 32-bit.

What could be the reason for the server to suddenly deny RDP connections?
I'm at my wit's end here. Any help is greatly appreciated.